# Horizontal Scrolling Using Vertical Mouse Wheel in Conjunction with CSS Scroll Snapping

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel

I am trying to map vertical mouse wheel user input to horizontal scrolling while maintaining compatibility with native CSS scroll snapping. Getting the page to scroll horizontally is rather easy as outlined in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/gOmgRzL

It’s getting it to work with native CSS scroll snapping that I’m having difficulties with as the approach of adding the deltaY of the wheel event to the scrollLeft value of the scrolling container doesn’t seem to work. I tried dispatching a custom wheel event with the deltaY of the original wheel event mapped to its deltaX property but apparently that custom wheel event does not actually trigger a scroll? Here is my unsuccessful code forked from the original CodePen:

```
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("main");

scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
  if (evt.deltaY != 0) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    
    // Custom wheel event
    const myEvent = new WheelEvent("wheel", {
      ...evt,
      bubbles: true,
      deltaX: evt.deltaY,
      view: evt.view
    });
    // evt.srcElement.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY; // only works with scroll-snap disabled on main element
  } else {
    // console.log(evt);
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/wandervogel/pen/zYJzjXZ?editors=0110

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.